# Media Query for screens above 1920x1080 to 2560x1600 including retina displays

Tags: responsive-design, media

I have used media queries for other resolutions which is as follows: @media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 0px) {...} @media (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width: 768px) {...} @media (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) {...}

Since the client wants specific look on these resolutions. But now on higher resolutions the website is distorting and i need the right query which says "Any screen resolutions above 1920x1080 including retina display should have this look". Else i feel i will have to write queries for specific famous resolutions above 1920x1080.

Comment: simply code using percentage. You don't need to say "above this" usually you code the max size and then downscaling using the media queries.
By the way, for retina display you should use the aspect ratio intead of the media queries like explained here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Yes i do agree to use percentages, but that did not serve to make the alignments and font-sizes exact as the client has given me in illustrator files for different resolutions.( I told clients that illustrations dont convert exact to websites but they arent ready to accept ). I did go through the above link  before and chose to have the following query: 'code' @media (min-width: 1921px) and (max-width: 2560px), (min-resolution: 2dppx) {...} 'code' but i am not quite sure how this will work on all resolutions above 1920x1080 including retina

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have a proper screen to test it on, right?
I mean, a screen with resolution higher thatn 1920

Comment: I have mac screens of 13.3 inch 2560x1600 retina display. I am thinking to use that as a threshold for all the screens between 1920 & 2560. Just wanted inputs from all fellow coders on what media query should i use for screens between 1920 & 2560 including retina displays. So is this fine  ' @media (min-width: 1921px) and (max-width: 2560px), (min-resolution: 2dppx) {...}  '

Comment: i'd use @media (min-width:1920px) without specify the max one.
And also, use 1920 instead of 1921

Answer (score 5):

//(1920x1080) Full HD Display

```
@media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 2560px)  {
    //insert styles here...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context to your answer? That is not a whole sentence, no valid CSS code,...

Comment: I have changed now @NicoHaase

Comment: That still does not look good: how does it solve the problem that the "website is distorting" above the width of 1920px? Why do you need that second part to restrict the width to a maximum of 2560px? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer, so they absolutely need some explanation to see why which parts are needed